# I have faced an issue in creating table with code in codeintor

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is my sql statement while creating table is give me an error please help where i'm wrong in this

```
CREATE TABLE `b_1_hold_orders` ( `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `products` TEXT NOT NULL, `order_type` INT(1) NOT NULL, `order_area` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `order_table` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `customer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `shipping_info` TEXT NULL, `order_note` TEXT NULL, `coupons` TEXT NULL, `customer_loyality_program` TEXT NULL, `tax_return` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `net_payable_amount` double(11) NOT NULL, `branch_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashier_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashier_login_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `order_date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', CONSTRAINT `pk_b_1_hold_orders` PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci



CREATE TABLE `b_1_hold_orders` ( `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `products` TEXT NOT NULL, `order_type` INT(1) NOT NULL, `order_area` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `order_table` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `customer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `shipping_info` TEXT NULL, `order_note` TEXT NULL, `coupons` TEXT NULL, `customer_loyality_program` TEXT NULL, `tax_return` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `net_payable_amount` double(11) NOT NULL, `branch_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashier_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashier_login_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `order_date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', CONSTRAINT `pk_b_1_hold_orders` PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Could you please include the error you're getting?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL, `branch_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashier_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashie' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the net_payable_amount field:

```
`net_payable_amount` DOUBLE(11) NOT NULL,
```

Double takes 2 parameters: the total number of digits and the number of digits after the decimal point. So depending on what you need, try changing it to something like:

```
`net_payable_amount` DOUBLE(11,4) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code double data type needs two parameters.

```
CREATE TABLE `b_1_hold_orders` ( `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `products` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`order_type` INT(1) NOT NULL, `order_area` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `order_table` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`customer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `shipping_info` TEXT NULL, `order_note` TEXT NULL, `coupons` TEXT NULL, 
`customer_loyality_program` TEXT NULL, `tax_return` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `net_payable_amount` double(11, 2) NOT NULL, 
`branch_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashier_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `cashier_login_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01', 
`order_date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01', CONSTRAINT `pk_b_1_hold_orders` PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

Also `0000-00-00` is not a valid date in mysql when  no_zero_mode is in strict_mode

[no_zero_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

I have added default date as 1970-01-01 for now.. Either you can change the date or you can make it nullable.. 
[Date time Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)